# Can I get DirectInput / XInput without the whole DirectX SDK?

Tags: directx, directinput

I am developing an in-house app that would use XInput or DirectInput to read from the Xbox 360 controller.  (I think it'll be the cheapest/easiest way to get multiple controls in the operator's hands.)

I will need to source-control all source and tools, which means also the SDK's.  I'd rather not take all of DirectX -- is DirectInput and XInput separable from the whole DirectX SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. Technically it would be possible to extract the required portions of the runtime, but if you look at the SDK EULA and redistribution agreement you will see that you're only allowed to install the full DirectX runtime.

Comment: He's talking about the SDK, not the runtime.